# TCP connection between different hosts on different connections

Tags: go, networking, tcp

I am trying to make a TCP connection where 2 hosts are on different networks. I have made a client and server in go lang

```
Server.go

func main() {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp",":8000")
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for{
        conn,err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil{
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
        go serve(conn)
    }

}

func serve(connection net.Conn){
    defer connection.Close()
    for{
        buffer := make([]byte,1024)
        _,err := connection.Read(buffer[:])
        if err != nil{
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(string(buffer))
    }
}
```

```
client.go

func main() {
    c, err := net.Dial("tcp",":8000")
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for scanner.Scan(){
        _,err := c.Write([]byte(scanner.Text()))
        if err != nil{
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}
```

when I run my server.go and use telnet on a device that is on the same network to send messages to the server, it works without any problem. I can send messages and it will show up in the console.

But when I try to run telnet on a device with a different network, it does not work. I try to send a message and nothing appears in the console. I then get a message something along the lines of connection closed by the foreign host.

I am a bit of a newbie in networking, I don't understand why is it not able to show any messages from another device on another network.

How do I achieve a TCP connection between 2 different hosts on different connections in go lang?

thanks.

Comment: 'I get a message along the line of ...' is not an acceptable problem statement.

Comment: The problem in that your connection is failing, it would really help to include the connection failure message.

Answer (score 1):

You should call through an external address, not a local address:
Find the external address of your server application host. Put it in client code:
For example:

```golang
c, err := net.Dial("tcp","45.44.230.205:8000")
```

That's it